# How can I get the query url of a github file?

Tags: git, github

I have a github repo with a `.csv` file and a `.xlsx`. I'm working with Klipfolio.

When I need to add my csv to Klipfolio I can use: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinbouhier/Klipfolio/master/abc.csv`
But when is a .xlsx file I can't open as `"Raw"`. Maybe I can use the Query URL but I don't know to get it.

Comment: then click "download zip" at https://github.com/martinbouhier/Klipfolio

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
https://github.com/martinbouhier/Klipfolio/blob/master/your-file.xlsx?raw=true
```

*your-file.xlsx* - should be your file name.

Or you can get the URL by yourself if open the required file on GitHub, then right click on 'View Raw' and copy the URL.